# gremlin order by with coalesce duplicates some values

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop

In some cases, I get inexplicable result when I use `order().by(...)` with `coalesce(...)`.
Using the standard Modern graph,

```
gremlin> g.V()
          .hasLabel("person")
          .out("created")
          .coalesce(values("name"), constant("x"))
          .fold()
==>[lop,lop,ripple,lop]
```

But if I sort by name before the coalesce I get 9 `lop` instead of 3:

```
gremlin> g.V()
          .hasLabel("person")
          .out("created")
          .order().by("name")
          .coalesce(values("name"), constant("x"))
          .fold()
==>[lop,lop,lop,lop,lop,lop,lop,lop,lop,ripple]
```

Why the number of elements differs between the two queries ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That looks like a bug - I've created an [issue in JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TINKERPOP-2100). There is a workaround but first consider that your traversal isn't really going to work even with the bug set aside, `order()` will fail because you're referencing a key that possibly doesn't exist in the `by()` modulator. So you need to account for that differently:

```
g.V().
  hasLabel("person").
  out("created").
  order().by(coalesce(values('name'),constant('x')))
```

I then used `choose()` to do what `coalesce()` is supposed to do:

```
g.V().
  hasLabel("person").
  out("created").
  order().by(coalesce(values('name'),constant('x'))).
  choose(has("name"),values('name'),constant('x')).
  fold()
```

and that seems to work fine.

Comment: you are a genius